# Grease pencil overlapping only in render view?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, grease-pencil, render-layers

I have a small room I'm working on, and I adjusted things to how I wanted them in the Layout tab. I did want to give it a slight hand drawn feel, so I know this means the strokes aren't super accurate. But there's a weird overlap of lines in the final render that doesn't seem to go away even when I deactivate the line layers, so I'm not certain if this is a bug or if I'm just too much of a beginner to identify the issue.

I have a thread of images regarding the issue here, and how it looks when I tried different solutions:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvNcm.jpg

I have the object stroke depth order set to 3D location. I'd really appreciate any suggestions you guys can give!

Comment: Seems to be a similar issue as this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177488/grease-pencil-strokes-showing-through-fills

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I had a similar problem and also no answers from any pros. The nearest I could figure is that you could try putting each piece on it's own layer and then organizing the layers having the correct ones on top to cover overlapping lines.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Z pass
(Blender 3.0.0) *Scene* > *View Layer* > *Passes* > *Data* > *Z*

[image]