# Grease pencil strokes showing through fills

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

In my grease pencil animation I'm getting strokes from the other side of my food truck showing through the fills of the front side on the early frames when the truck is further away and they slowly go away as the truck moves closer. It's particularly noticeable on the front wheels and windshield. Is there a setting that I'm missing that can correct this issue?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a similar issue as this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176575/grease-pencil-overlapping-only-in-render-view#